# Entries only visible for User and certain role

Tags: 2sxc

What I need is a simple app where people can write down a 'diary'. The entries are only visible for the user itself and maybe for a mentor (role).

How would you take that on? 
Is there a filter ‘show only own entries’?

Cheers
Tycho

Comment: What is DNN & 2SXC?

Comment: @muhammad DNN is a content management system, 2sxc enables me to create ‘apps’ to show great looking content while still mainainable for editors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW: You can also set content-type permissions so
1. registered users can create new items
2. owners (the people who created it) can also edit the items

This allows for building all kinds of solutions like the one above ;)

Comment: That's what I tried initially because that would be way more powerful. But somehow this did not work. If you can spare 3 minutes, I recorded what I have and what is (not) happening on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o956MuNEuUQ 
I'll bring a very cool set of Tjep's gloves to Champery if you can point me to the right button/direction :-)

Comment: You're on the right track - but I think you forgot to ensure that the edit is enabled (which is not the case for non-admins). Check out https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/razor-edit.enable and also the main blog explaining this https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/recipe-create-public-forms-with-2sxc

Comment: I owe the very cool, yet warm Tjep's gloves that even allow you to use your smart phone. I can not find anymore where I got it, but thanks to your pointers, I ended up with :

@Edit.Enable(api: true, forms: true, context: true, autoToolbar: false)

<script>
    // simple function to run the command and handle the returned promise
    function addProject(tag) {
        $2sxc.cms.run(tag, "new", { contentType: "Diary"})
            .then(function () {
                alert("Thanks - we'll review your entry and publish it.")
            });
    }
</script>

Like a charm :-)

Comment: Found it again. The code snippet was on:
https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/javascript-%242sxc.cms

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the Ownerfilter in the querydesigner. And that does exactly what I need.